# Can MegaRAID controllers use their writeback cache in JBOD mode?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, megaraid, storcli, mdraid

[Similar to this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/862470/does-a-raid-controller-use-cache-in-jbod-mode), but for Broadcom/LSI controllers: Can MegaRAID controllers use the onboard disk cache for JBOD drives? (I would like to enable the controller's hardware cache and then use mdraid on the drives directly.)

This would increase performance by coalescing random writes in the controller's write cache for sequential writeback by the controller.

I found this in the storcli that hints at the possibility:

```bash
# storcli  /c0 show all 2>&1 | grep -i cache  | grep -i jbod
Support JBOD Write cache = No
```

So, how do you set "Support JBOD Write cache" to yes?  What setting changes are needed using `storecli` (or another command) to enable JBOD writeback caching?

I know that `storcli /c1/e56/s3 set jbod` will set a disk to JBOD mode, but I'm not sure how to tell it to be cached in write-back mode. Has anyone seen this option or used it in production? Any detail you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

After googling for "Support JBOD Write cache = Yes", it seems that all ocurrences also have "Support JBOD = Yes" and "Enable JBOD = Yes".  Perhaps this a pre-requisite.

Comment: No, this is not possible. Why do you think you want this?

Comment: @ewwhite for random write performance. updated post

Comment: ZFS does this on its own using RAM.

Comment: @ewwhite perhaps, but the question is about the raid controller, not about ZFS, that was just an example.  The question is:  How can you set `Support JBOD Write cache = Yes` as shown by the example `storcli` command above?